# How to test/develop packages in R in isolated environment? that is, independent of the packages already installed in the system

Tags: r, development-environment, virtual-environment

Here is a example situation: I have a `tidyr` `v0.8.0` already installed, but let's say I want to tinker with a `tidyr` `v0.8.2` without affecting my current system. How do you do this?

In python, I can make a virtual environment or conda environment and install the dependencies, but I am not sure what's the similar approach in R. I know `packrat` exists for dependency management, but the individual package such as`tidyr` doesn't come with `packrat` directory.

Anyway, currently, if I use the following commands, I get an error

```
git clone https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr.git
cd tidyr && git checkout v0.8.2
open tidyr.Rproj # open Rstudio project

# in Rstudio
> devtools::test()
```

like this

```
Loading tidyr
Loading required package: testthat
Testing tidyr
test-append.R: ..........
complete: .........
drop_na: ..........
expand: .....1.................
Extract: ..........
fill: .................
full_seq: .....
Gather: 23456789abcdefFFFFEEEEEEE
id: ...
nest: EEEEEEE
replace_na: .......
test-separate-rows.R: ..............
Separate: .....................................
Spread: W....................................................
test-uncount.R: ......
Deprecated SE variants: E....EE..EEEE......EE.
unite: EEEEE
unnest: ...............................
```

I think this is happening because it's using system's `tidyr` rather than developmental version

```
> packageVersion("tidyr")
[1] ‘0.8.0’
```

So going back to my original question,

how do you do the isolated package development in R?